# Creating the @< BIP in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, compare

I'm basically trying to create 'my own' version of the @< operator in prolog, i.e. something to the tune of at_less(F1,F2), where it returns true if F1@

So some example inputs:

```
?- at_less(1.2,0)
yes
?-at_less(0,1.2)
no
?-at_less(f(1,2,a),f(1,2,b)).
yes
```

Obviously I don't want to use the @< operator, as that would be redundant :)
I can understand how one would compare two atoms, with something like

```
%atom_pr(+A1,+A2): A1 @< A2, where A1 and A2 are atoms.

atom_pr(L1,L2):-
    atom_codes(L1,First), %atom codes for first
    atom_codes(L2,Second),%atom codes for second
    code_compare(First,Second). %compare the codes, return true or false

code_compare([HF|TF],[HS|TS]):-
    (   HF=HS ->
    code_compare(TF,TS)
    ;
    HF<HS ->
    true
    ;
    fail
    ).
code_compare([],X):-
    true.
code_compare([],[]).

%(I understand this is probably not the most efficient way of going about this, but I'm %just beginning!)
```

Is there something similar I can do for all constants, rather than just atoms? Is there a command similar to atom_codes/2? If not, the only thing I can think of doing is breaking it into a great number of if -> else statements, checking to see if the first is an atom and the second isn't etc. etc., but this seems like a kinda tedious/poor method perhaps?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Edit: Thanks to the help below, I've gotten a program running that is functional (at least from what I can tell). I've put it in the code below, in case someone else wanders here. I believe it is, however, extremely inefficient, so there's plenty of room for improvement :)

```
%flat_pr(+F1, +F2): F1@<F2, where F1 and F2 are flat ground terms
flat_pr(F1,F2):-

    (   compound(F1) ->   %these ifs here to check what type F1 and F2 are
    (   compound(F2) ->   %comparing/succeeding/failing as appropriate
    compound_compare(F1,F2) %(atom>integer>float>compound)
    ;                       % I believe these ifs could definitely be cut down though
    (   atom(F2) ->
    true
    ;
    (   float(F2) ->
    true
    ;
    (   integer(F2) ->
    true
    )
    )
    )
    )
    )

    ;

    (   atom(F1) ->
    (   compound(F2) ->
    false

    ;
    (   atom(F2) ->
    atom_pr(F1,F2)
    ;
    (   float(F2) ->
    false
    ;
    (   integer(F2) ->
    false
    )
    )
    )
    )
    )

    ;

    (   float(F1) ->
    (   compound(F2) ->
    false

    ;
    (   atom(F2) ->
    true

    ;
    (   float(F2) ->
    number_pr(F1,F2)
    ;
    (   integer(F2) ->
    true
    )
    )
    )
    )
    ;
    fail
    )

    ;

    (   integer(F1) ->
    (   compound(F2) ->
    false

    ;
    (   atom(F2) ->
    true

    ;
    (   float(F2) ->
    false

    ;
    (   integer(F2) ->
    number_pr(F1,F2)
    )
    )
    )
    )
    )
    .

compound_compare(F1,F2):-  %compares compounds (arity first)
    functor(F1,N1,A1),    %get arity
    functor(F2,N2,A2),
        (   A1<A2 ->      %compare arity
    true
    ;
    (   A1>A2 ->
    false
    )
    ;
    (   A1=A2 ->      %if arity the same
    F1 =.. L1,       %compound -> list
    F2 =.. L2,
    list_compare(L1,L2)  %compare the lists
    )
    )
    .

list_compare([],[]).  %base case
list_compare([H|T],[H1|T1]):-
    (   flat_pr(H,H1) ->    %if H@<H1
    list_compare(T,T1)     %compare Tails
    ;
    false               %else false
    )
    .

atom_pr(L1,L2):-
    atom_codes(L1,First), %atom codes for first
    atom_codes(L2,Second),%atom codes for second
    code_compare(First,Second). %compare the codes, return true or false

number_pr(L1,L2):-   %simple number comparison...straight forward
    (   L1=<L2 ->
    true
    ;
    fail
    ).

code_compare([HF|TF],[HS|TS]):- %just runs through atom codes
    (   HF=HS ->
    code_compare(TF,TS)
    ;
    HF<HS ->
    true
    ;
    fail
    ).
code_compare([],X):-
    true.
code_compare([],[]).
```

I'd love to see ways to improve this though! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about BIN-Prolog but in SWI-Prolog atom_codes does the trick:

```
?- atom_codes('jack\&^',K). 
K = [106, 97, 99, 107, 38, 94].

?- atom_codes('17.2345',K). 
K = [49, 55, 46, 50, 51, 52, 53].
```

**Update:**
If you need to compare terms, 1) freeze them (see further) to make the terms ground and 2) use unif (=..) to transform a term to a list, e.g., f(1,2) becomes [f,1,2], and then for each element: a) if it is an atom or a number, then use atom_codes; b) if it is a term, apply the same procedure recursively.

Freezing ensures that the variables are compared in order of their appearance. By "freezing" I mean the following predicate taken from the classical Sterling and Shapiro's book "The Art of Prolog":

```
numvars('#VAR'(N),N,N1) :- N1 is N+1.
numvars(Term,N1,N2) :- nonvar(Term), functor(Term,_,N),
                          numvars(0,N,Term,N1,N2).
numvars(N,N,_,N1,N1).
numvars(I,N,Term,N1,N3) :- I<N, I1 is I+1,
          arg(I1,Term,Arg), numvars(Arg,N1,N2),
          numvars(I1,N,Term,N2,N3).

frz(A,B) :- frz(A,B,0).
frz(A,B,Min) :- copy_term(A,B), numvars(B,Min,_),!.
```

Comment: Atom codes is helpful in certain respects, but how should I go about dealing with something like "f(1,2,a,3)"? atom_codes(f(1,2,a,3)) gives me an error?

Comment: I've updated my answer since I cannot include a code fragment in a comment.

Comment: Thanks so much; the freezing thing is a little over my head I think :)
(I was basically assuming I was working with flat ground terms, at least for the time being). The =.. is very helpful though! if I understand you correctly, you're suggesting I turn compounds into lists, and then just use atom_codes to compare them (and =.. should this list contain compounds)?

Comment: Yes. If the list you have obtained contains terms (I think that you call them "compounds") you should repeat the procedure recursively. If it does not work out, and you are really desperate, tomorrow I can write the solution for you...

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I believe I have it working now :) Thank you so much for your help!